# Restore Toolbox in Left-side sidebar in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, sidebar, toolbox

I know how to open the Toolbox, thank you. I like having it on the left-side (vertical) sidebar and I accidentally deleted it. I have found no way to restore it. Please help.

Comment: Use View > Toolbox

Comment: Not to repeat myself, but I do know how to open the Toolbox, I really do. I want to know how to pin it onto the left side, in vertical text, just like I have Data Sources, Server Explorer, etc.

Comment: You don't know how to move it?  Don't know how to dock it?  Don't know how to pin it?  Consider Window > Reset Window Layout.

Comment: Thank you! Window > Reset Layout put it exactly where I want it.

Answer (score 0):

Click view at the top and drop down to "toolbox" or any item, then when it opens click drag the window to the left side in the docked position. After it is docked on the left side click the "pin icon" at the top "autohide".
Repeat for other windows!

NOTE: The window has to be on the left-side in order to add to the sidebar (vertical tabs). Hope this helps!
[Image of autohide option while toolbox window is located on the left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqTS3.png)